# Understanding the syntax of Agda

Tags: syntax, agda

Using the following as an example

```
postulate DNE : {A : Set} → ¬ (¬ A) → A

data ∨ (A B : Set) : Set where
  inl : A → A ∨ B
  inr : B → A ∨ B

-- Use double negation to prove exclude middle

classical-2 : {A : Set} → A ∨ ¬ A
classical-2 = λ {A} → DNE (λ z → z (inr (λ x → z (inl x)))
```

I know this is correct, purely because of how agda works, but I am new to this language and can't get my head around how its syntax works, I would appreciate if anyone can walk me through what is going on, thanks :)

I have experience in haskell, although that was around a year ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with the postulate. The syntax is simply:

```
postulate name : type
```

This asserts that there exists some value of type `type` called `name`. Think of it as axioms in logic - things that are defined to be true and are not be questioned (by Agda, in this case).

---

Next up is the data definition. There's a slight oversight with the mixfix declaration so I'll fix it and explain what it does. The first line:

```
data _∨_ (A B : Set) : Set where
```

Introduces a new type (constructor) called `_∨_`. `_∨_` takes two arguments of type `Set` and then returns a `Set`.

I'll compare it with Haskell. The `A` and `B` are more or less equivalent to `a` and `b` in the following example:

```
data Or a b = Inl a | Inr b
```

This means that the data definition defines a polymorphic type (a template or a generic, if you will). `Set` is the Agda equivalent of Haskell's `*`.

---

What's up with the underscores? Agda allows you to define arbitrary operators (prefix, postfix, infix... usually just called by a single name - mixfix). The underscores just tell Agda where the arguments are. This is best seen with prefix/postfix operators:

```
-_ : Integer → Integer   -- unary minus
- n = 0 - n

_++ : Integer → Integer   -- postfix increment
x ++ = x + 1
```

You can even create crazy operators such as:

```
if_then_else_ : ...
```

---

Next part is definition of the data constructors itself. If you've seen Haskell's GADTs, this is more or less the same thing. If you haven't:

When you define a constructor in Haskell, say `Inr` above, you just specify the type of the arguments and Haskell figures out the type of the whole thing, that is `Inr :: b -> Or a b`. When you write GADTs or define data types in Agda, you need to specify the whole type (and there are good reasons for this, but I won't get into that now).

So, the data definition specifies two constructors, `inl` of type `A → A ∨ B` and `inr` of type `B → A ∨ B`.

---

Now comes the fun part: first line of `classical-2` is a simple type declaration. What's up with the `Set` thing? When you write polymorphic functions in Haskell, you just use lower case letters to represent type variables, say:

```
id :: a -> a
```

What you really mean is:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
```

And what you *really* mean is:

```
id :: forall (a :: *). a -> a
```

I.e. it's not just any kind of `a`, but that `a` is a type. Agda makes you do this extra step and declare this quantification explicitly (that's because you can quantify over more things than just types).

And the curly braces? Let me use the Haskell example above again. When you use the `id` function somewhere, say `id 5`, you don't need to specify that `a = Integer`.

If you used normal paretheses, you'd have to provide the actual type `A` everytime you called `classical-2`. However, most of the time, the type can be deduced from the context (much like the `id 5` example above), so for those cases, you can "hide" the argument. Agda then tries to fill that in automatically - and if it cannot, it complains.

---

And for the last line: `λ x → y` is the Agda way of saying `\x -> y`. That should explain most of the line, the only thing that remains are the curly braces yet again. I'm fairly sure that you can omit them here, but anyways: hidden arguments do what they say - they hide. So when you define a function from `{A}` to `B`, you just provide something of type `B` (because `{A}` is hidden). In some cases, you need to know the value of the hidden argument and that's what this special kind of lambda does: `λ {A} →` allows you to access the hidden A!